# Inner HTML repalce not working on add to any

Tags: javascript, share

Spent hours on this and don't understand that behavior. Any advice would be appreciated.

If you look below you load this code you will see the toolbar for sharing with add to any plugin that is what the page.js is including control for.

You can see I have commented out a foo bar at the bottom. That works just fine after load. I hit the button and the foo turns into a bar. When I load the entire div though I am trying to change the text ultimately by what I put in the insert form. An odd thing happens the entire add to any button dissapears. Any idea why? Is the page reloading and cannot grab the .js file or something bizarre like that?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
<script>
function second(){
//document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'bar';
document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = '<div class=\"a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style\"> <a class=\"a2a_dd\" href=\"https://www.addtoany.com/share\"></a></div>';
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="foo" id="foo"></input>
<input type="button" onClick="second();first();"></input>
</form>
<div id="hello"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = '<div class=\"a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style\"><a class=\"a2a_dd\" href=\"https://www.addtoany.com/share\"></a></div>';                   
//document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'foo';
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: remove form and it will work fine

Comment: You are correct however the reason the form is there because my plan or goal was to take the information collected from the form and use it to create a dynamic hyperlink for the share button to share. This is used with a google maps API so I was going to use the address shared into the form so that when people come back to the site from the share they can see the markers the last person was looking at that shared it.